# GET parameters raise a 406 error

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, utf-8, get

I have this simple PHP script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es-ES">
<head>
    <meta charset="iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body><p><?php

if(isset($_GET['echo'])){
    echo $_GET['echo'];
}

?></p>
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="echo" value="" />
</form>
<p>áéíóúàèìòùñ</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Submitting the spanish word "cañón" generates the GET parameter string `?echo=ca%F1%F3n`, that my hosting answers with a `406 Not Acceptable` error. It's important to me to keep the charset `iso-8859-1`, and have the script file codified in ANSI.

Using the `accept-charset="UTF-8"` attribute in the form element dodges the error, but the word echoed into the page shows as "caÃ±Ã³n".

Is there some way of configuring Apache, hopefully using `.htaccess`, for avoiding this behaviour and rendering correctly the word "cañón" on the resulting page?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: I know, Quentin. It's just a test script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the solution to the problem was to ask to my hosting to check the `mod_security` configuration. They fixed it in some way, and now the script works fine.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can't use the word 'echo' as a variable since it is one of the php syntax words. Try using a different variable.

Comment: No, it's not true. Try replacing $echo with $e, for example. Nothing changes.